# unable to open /dev/mem on raspberry pi 4b

Tags: raspberry-pi

Please can anyone help?! I'm trying to read Raspberry Pi 4b GPIO pins in assembler using direct memory access, and need to open /dev/mem. I'm aspplying the info from the book "Raspberry Pi assembly language programming" by Stephen Smith. According to his book, the command for accessing /dev/mem is "openFile devmem", but it just returns " error 1b6" when I compile using gcc. If any of you clever guys can help or even provide me with a code sample to get around this problem, I'd be most grateful - really tearing my hair out trying to solve this one! Thanks, Paul.

Comment: Try running under root user, e.g. with `sudo YourProgram`

Comment: Thanks Mark, problem occurs when I compile with gcc then  debug using gdb. I'm not doing something right!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.